# What's the fastest way to serialize and deserialize a list of objects in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, performance, serialization

I need the fastest method to deserialize a large list (20000 items) of a custom class where the class only contains integers, floats and string attributes.

Should I use pickle, cPickle, json or something else?

So far I tried pickle which crashes when I try to load. I tried to use json.dumps and it errors out saying my custom type is not serializable.

```
class MyType
...

list = []
for i in range(10000):
    list.append(MyType(i))

list.serialize?
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that the class only contains simple types like integers, floats and strings, you could use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module and it should be fast.  Something like this for two integers (32 bits each), a float (double), and a string (up to 20 characters):

```
codec = struct.Struct('<iid20s')
size = codec.size
buf = bytearray(size * len(items))

offset = 0
for item in items):
    codec.pack_into(buf, offset, item.int1, item.int2, item.float1, item.string1)
    offset += size
```

Now `buf` contains all the data and can be written to a file.